# Unresolved reference : removeAt()

Tags: kotlin

I was using the removeAt function and it was just working fine but then suddenly the compiler started to throw the error unresolved reference : removeAt

Here is the code:

```
fun main() {
 val nums = mutableListOf(-3, 167, 0, 9, 212, 3, 5, 665, 5, 8) // this is just a list
 var newList = nums.sorted() // this is the sorted list
 var finall = mutableListOf<Int>() // this is an empty list that will contain all the removed elements 
 for(i in 1..3) {
     var min: Int = newList.removeAt(0) // element removed from newList is saved from min variable
     // above line is producing the error 
     
     finall.add(min) // then the min variable is added to the empty list created before
     
 }
 
 println(finall)
 println(newList)

 
}
```

I have studied a bunch of documentries but I'm unable to find my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd line, where you sort the list, returns a list not a mutableList. So newList is non-mutable. Replacing that 3rd line with `var newList = nums.sorted().toMutableList()` will make newList mutable and solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `nums.sorted()` is an immutable list, which means you cannot change it, or in other words, remove elements.

You need to tell kotlin you want a mutable list `var newList = nums.sorted().toMutableList()`

Answer (score 0):

because `newList` is List object. List object no method removeAt

you need using `newList.toMutableList().removeAt()`

Comment: What would be the point of that?  It would create a mutable copy of the list, remove an item from it, and then discard the copy, leaving the original unchanged.

Comment: hi @gidds I'm just explaining why he doesn't see the `removeAt ()` function.